# wrong macro expansion for $dir in vscode windows

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

### Actual behavior

in settings.json , when we use `$dir` in any settings , it takes backward slash as separator and becoz of that "path1\path2\path3\"  , since it includes a backward slash at end of path , that end quotes " gets ignored and it throws me a file not found error .

### Expected  behavior

`$dir` should resolve to `"path1\\path2\\path3\\"`  or `"path1/path2/path3/"` (with forward slashes)

**Also using ${relativeFile} or ${fileDirname} doesn't resolve at all in settings.json and $relativeFile and $fileDirname also don't resolve (they just resolve into literal ${relativeFile} strings)**

How to fix this ?